# JmsMessagingTemplate issue ( Spring boot 1.2.5 release)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

When I startup Spring boot with **IntelliJ IDEA in debug or run mode**,**It works well** ,But when I input below command in cmd:

> C:\Users\Administrator> gradle build

Then I get a runnable jar,eg:**abc.jar**,Then I run the jar with below command:

> java -jar  abc.jar

I got these issues

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:   Could not autowire field: private cn.vamos.reg.service.PushService cn.vamos.reg.controller.LoginController.pushService;   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pushService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate cn.vamos.reg.service.PushServiceImpl.jmsMessagingTemplate;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
```

**Here is Pom file**

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>cn.vamos.VmsApplication</start-class>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.23</tomcat.version>
    <blazeds.version>4.7.0</blazeds.version>
    <activemq.version>5.11.1</activemq.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring-flex -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.flex</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-flex-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flex.blazeds</groupId>
        <artifactId>flex-messaging-core</artifactId>
        <version>${blazeds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flex.blazeds</groupId>
        <artifactId>flex-messaging-common</artifactId>
        <version>${blazeds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flex.blazeds</groupId>
        <artifactId>flex-messaging-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>${blazeds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flex.blazeds</groupId>
        <artifactId>flex-messaging-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>${blazeds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-mqtt</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: If that works in the IDE, I can only suspect a packaging issue. I don't know about commond but without looking at the code it's hard to understand what's going on. Can you maybe remove that dependency as you'll probably get another exception that reveals that the JMS support isn't enabled or something.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll Hi Nicoll,Sorry for my little careless.I have modified the format

Comment: I fail to see what could go wrong. Can you share a sample that reproduces the problem?